# Run programs on other computer in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, remoting

I am using asp.net and c#.

I know it sounds weird and unusual but I have got a requirement like this: I want to know how I can run an exe or take some control of a user's computer. Please note that when I say user computer I mean only 2-3 computers on which I have admin privileges.

So, the complete requirement is that I have to control other computers for which I have admin user and password in asp.net.

Please tell me if it's possible to do this and if yes how.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have the admin credentials, why not use RDC?

Comment: What kind of access? Do you want to a command line? Do you want to run arbitrary code? Do you want to control a GUI session?

Comment: Let me explain it more, User will press a button which runs a exe on one of the system. These are 2-3 systems and for them I have got credientials. I can't use Remote Desktop connection as user will click the button and he is not the one who will run the connection, in fact he should not be aware about this internal process.

Comment: Why is asp.net relevant?

Comment: What do these EXE do? Why do you need executables? Can't you download the exe and execute it?

Comment: It's a like of process that user will initiate, which will run of these computers. It's related to asp.net because asp.net user will run this exe. They may be from any part of the world and it's like a simple website and user will not be aware about this internal process.

Comment: use can not download this exe, as it should run on one of those computers. These exe will do some SAP workflow about which I am not aware, it is already their and dosen't come under our project scope, even I don't have any documentation of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use [Pstools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx).

Comment: Seems like work for me but how to control pstool with asp.net ?

Comment: Specifically you want to use psexec.  You run that like anything else using the Process.Start method.